# How to separate objects created using mirror modifier in Blender?

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I am using Blender 2.56. I created all body parts of humanoid model.

I used mirror modifier on individual body parts separately. Now I have to merg all the parts to make full body.

Now my question is I want to make changes on only left hand not on both of them.

But mirror modifier is making the changes on both at a time. I applied the mirror modifier even then when I am coming to edit mode and doing some changes both hands are getting modified.

How to separate those both hands and make them independent ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In fact I got the solution in some other place.

To make the hands separate objects just <kbd>Tab</kbd> into edit mode, select all verts (<kbd>A</kbd>) and hit <kbd>P</kbd>.

Choose *Separate by loose parts*.

<kbd>Tab</kbd> into object mode and they will be two separate objects.

Comment: I wonder if there is not a python function as a duplicate and mirror button?

Comment: If you're newly mirroring-and-separating an object, remember to actually _apply_ the mirror modifier before tabbing into edit mode. The separation won't work otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

In the Tools sidebar (Press <kbd>T</kbd> to show) there is an X mirror option that is meant to help if you need to make adjustments after you apply a mirror modifier. Check that this is turned off. Are you also sure that you didn't have more than one mirror modifier? maybe re-added after merging different objects?

[image]

Version 2.56 is getting very old so it may look different.

Comment: I have a option 'X Mirror' under the 'mesh options' , but nothing is happening if I turn off. I am not more than one mirror modifier.